# Problem with instance setup on aws ec2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, server, instance

Created an instance on aws ec2 and right after the initial setup everything works. But after some time (about the next day) the server seems to lose connection to the internet. I can connect to it, but I can't download any packets. I can't execute any curl requests either. The problem is only solved if I create an image of the server and then create a new configuration, but the next day the problem comes back. Any idea how to solve the problem?

When creating the instance, the network settings were selected as standard. Ubuntu 18.04

Example output:

```
apt update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                           
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
Err:2 http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                      
  Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.229.225.193), connection timed out Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.246.214.20), connection timed out Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.253.229.19), connection timed out Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.241.117.189), connection timed out Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.229.116.227), connection timed out Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.253.189.82), connection timed out
Err:3 http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
35 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.229.225.193), connection timed out Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.246.214.20), connection timed out Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.253.229.19), connection timed out Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.241.117.189), connection timed out Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.229.116.227), connection timed out Could not connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.253.189.82), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

That error could be related to DNS as well and not necessary to internet connectivity. Since you're connected to the vm via SSH, the VM has internet access right?

I would change the DNS servers in resolv.conf. Something like this will do:

```
echo > /etc/resolv.conf <<EOF
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
EOF
```

Then try again, see if it's working.